# Anonymous Hash Slices - syntax?

Tags: perl

I love hash slices and use them frequently:

```
my %h;
@h{@keys}=@vals;
```

Works brilliantly!  But 2 things have always vexed me.

First, is it possible to combine the 2 lines above into a single line of code?  It would be nice to declare the hash and populate it all at once.

Second, is it possible to slice an existing anonymous hash... something like:

```
my $slice=$anonh->{@fields}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your first question, to do it in a single line of code:

```
@$_{@keys}=@vals for \my %h;
```

or

```
map @$_{@keys}=@vals, \my %h;
```

but I wouldn't do that; it's a confusing way to write it.

Either version declares the variable and immediately takes a reference to it and aliases `$_` to the reference so that the hash reference can be used in a slice.  This lets you declare the variable in the existing scope; `@{ \my %h }{@keys} = @vals;` also "works", but has the unfortunate drawback of scoping `%h` to that tiny block in the hash slice.

For your second question, as shown above, slices can be used on hash references; see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference for some easy to remember rules.

```
my @slice = @$anonh{@fields};
```

or maybe you meant:

```
my $slice = [ @$anonh{@fields} ];
```

but @slice/$slice there is a copy of the values.  To get an array of aliases to the hash values, you can do:

```
my $slice = sub { \@_ }->( @$anonh{@fields} );
```

Comment: Those one-liners are much less of an abomination than the `$h->{$a}=$b while ($a,$b)=($ea//=List::MoreUtils::each_array(@keys,@values))->()` I was working on.

Comment: @mob: `%h = Algorithm::Loops::MapCarE {@_} \@keys, \@values;`

Comment: So many good answers... accepted this one because it was first.  :-)

Comment: Could you explain what the specific interaction between `\` and `my` is/are ?

Answer (score 9):

- First question:

  ```
  my %h = map { $keys[$_] => $vals[$_] } 0..$#keys;
  ```

  or

  ```
  use List::MoreUtils qw( mesh );

  my %h = mesh @keys, @vals;
  ```
- Second question:

  If it's `...NAME...` for a hash, it's `...{ $href }...` for a hash ref, so

  ```
  my @slice = @hash{@fields};
  ```

  is

  ```
  my @slice = @{ $anonh }{@fields};
  ```

  The curlies are optional if the reference expression is a variable.

  ```
  my @slice = @$anonh{@fields};
  ```

  - [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
  - [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
  - [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
  - [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
  - [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
  - [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Answer (score 3):

Hash slice syntax is

```
@ <hash-name-or-hash-ref> { LIST }
```

When you are slicing a hash reference, enclose it in curly braces so it doesn't get dereferenced as an array. This gives you:

```
my @values = @{$anonh}{@fields}
```

for a hash reference `$anonh`.