# Add multiple keys to an anonymous hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash that holds for each record an anonymous hash with 2 elements: an array and a hash. I want to initialize this subsidiary hash with a list of keys.

I know hash slices can be used when you use a normal hash (not a ref) and use both a key list and values list.

My code is like this

```
my %records;
my $key = "key1";
my @states = ( "state1", "state2", "state3" );

$records{$key} = {
    numbers => [],
    states  => %{@states} #This is wrong !
};
```

EDIT (marked as duplicate): This question asks how to add multiple keys to **an anonymous hash**.

Comment: Slices are cool, but you don't have to use them everywhere. Just do `my $states = { ... }; $records{$key} = { states => $states };`

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't be using it everywhere. I was just wondering if there was a shorter version than the one you described. Thanks !

Comment: At the end of your program you could try adding `@{$records{$key}->{states}}{@states}=undef` . It will initialize the second hash with the given keys.

Comment: or `states => { map { $_ => undef } @states }`.

Comment: I could have sworn somebody asked this before, but the closest I could find was [Anonymous Hash Slices - syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17837665/176646)

Comment: Shorter is not always better. Generally you should shoot for readability rather than brevity.

Comment: @choroba I would prefer your solution since I can use it upon theinitialisation of the main anonymous hash.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, the closest I found by scrolling through the question suggestions were hash slices but not for an anonymous hash.

Comment: You should show what you want `%records` to look like. It's puzzling that you have only keys for your hash and no values

Comment: @Agnaroc: A hash is a hash, whether it has a name or not. I think what's puzzling you is how to create and populate a hash using the `{ ... }` constructor, and the answer is that there's no need to. You can build an ordinary hash and take a reference to it, and it will be as if the hash were anonymous

Answer (score 3):

It's puzzling that you have only keys for your hash and no values. This code will set the value of each element of `$records{$key}{states}` to `undef`

```
my %records;
my $key = "key1";
my @states = ( "state1", "state2", "state3" );

$records{$key} = {
    numbers => [],
    states  => { map { ( $_ => undef ) } @states },
};
```

But it would be clearer to build a proper hash temporarily and assign a reference to it to the data structure. I've enclosed the entire assignment process in its own block so that I can declare a temporary lexical hash `%states`

```
{
    my %states;
    @states{@states} = ();

    $records{$key} = {
        numbers => [],
        states  => \%states,
    };
}
```

But note that it's generally better if hash elements don't exist at all rather than create them with undefined values. There is no need to preallocate the elements of a hash like this, just leave it empty like you did with the array

```
$records{$key} = {
    numbers => [],
    states  => {},
}
```